# IIS WCF Service not using app.config

Tags: wcf, iis, .net-3.5, web-config

I have a .NET 3.5 WCF service hosted in IIS. The project service library has an app.config file with some configuration settings (Database connection strings, etc.). I deploy the project via a website project in Visual Studio, which generates a web.config to manage the endpoints. Is there a way I can put the app.config settings from my service library in to the web.config? The IIS hosted service seems to be using default values from the settings designer, and ignoring even an expliclty copied in app.config. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that a DLL can not utliize an app.config.

My service application is set up to pull the settings settings from the `[MyAssembly].Properties.Settings.Default` namespace.

Comment: when the WCF service is hosted in IIS, it's behaving like a web app and thus will be using a **`web.config`** - not its app.config .... Also: the .NET configuration system never uses the `app.config` for a class library - you need to put the settings into the **hosting app's** configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use external configuration files?

Your web.config:

```
<config>
  ...
  <connectionStrings configSource="myConnections.config"></connectionStrings>
</config>
```

And then your external myConnections.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add ... />
</connectionStrings>
```

You can have multiple external configuration files referenced from your main web.config file.  See see [this blog post](http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx) for a nice explanation of how/why to do this.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The service code is currently configured to pull out the settings from the   [MyAssembly].Properties.Settings.Default namespace. Would the external connections configuration file define the settings in that same namespace?

Comment: I created a settings file for a simple console app I have, and created a connection string in Settings.  In my app.config, I see this:    `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestCache1.Properties.Settings.Setting" connectionString="Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`.  So I don't see why I can't change that to pull my connection string out into an external file and reference it as I do in my answer above.  It seems to work.

Comment: branching off your idea, I realized that I was able to put the settings directly in the web.config. I put the connection strings right in the (by default, empty) <connectionStrings> section, and added an appSettings sectionGroup (like in my app.config) there. The key here was using the Assembly name that the service library is looking for. Thanks. I defintely see how an external configuration file would work, however, I think putting them in web.config suffices for now.